# Deleting rows with odd numbers in a text file in Python

Tags: python, loops, txt

I want to delete every column with odd numbers in column 1 or 2 from this text file.

I am not sure how to write the loop for this.

Comment: no text file format showing

Comment: Do you mean the index of the column is odd, or the value is odd? Also do you only want to delete just that one square, or the whole row? An example might help.